# Python 'with' and extra arguments to logging

Tags: python, logging, with-statement

Is it possible to add extra information to logger over the `with` function?

I need something like this

```
some_class.py
def some_function():
   with monitoring.context(1, 2):
       logger.info('message')

monitoring.py

@contextmanager
def context(id, id2):
   //any way how to adds ids to formatter
   yield
```

Thank's for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def some_function():
   with monitoring.context(1, 2) as ctx_dict:
       logger.info('message', **ctx_dict)

def context(id, id2):
   yield {'some': id, 'another': id2}
```

Of course, API for your `logger.info` have to accept `some` and `another` keyword arguments.

Comment: Thank's its ok! Is possible set in format these parameters as optional? 
In this format: '%(some)s %(another)s'